# k8s - how to project service account token into pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to project the serviceAccount token into my pod as described in this k8s doc - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection.

I create a service account using below command

```
kubectl create sa acct
```

Then I create the pod

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
      name: vault-token
  serviceAccountName: acct
  volumes:
  - name: vault-token
    projected:
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          path: vault-token
          expirationSeconds: 7200
```

It fails due to - `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "vault-token" : failed to fetch token: the server could not find the requested resource`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    5m15s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  65s (x10 over 5m15s)  kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "vault-token" : failed to fetch token: the server could not find the requested resource
```

My minikube version: v0.33.1

kubectl version : 1.13

**Question:**

- What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you started the api server with the necessary flags as mentioned in the doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this on kubeadm, and was able to suceed. 
@Aman Juneja was right, you have to add the API flags as described in the documentation.

You can do that by creating the serviceaccount and then adding this flags to the kubeapi:

`sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

```
- --service-account-issuer=api
- --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
- --service-account-api-audiences=api
```

After that apply your pod.yaml and it will work. As you will see in describe pod:

```
Volumes:
  vault-token:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
```

[removed as not working solution]

unfortunately in my case my minikube did not want to start with this flags, it gets stuck on: `waiting for pods: apiserver` soon I will try to debug again.

**UPDATE**

Turns out you have to just pass the arguments into the minikube with directories from the inside of minikubeVM and not the outside as I did with previous example (so the .minikube directory), so it will look like this:

```
minikube start \
 --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.key \
  --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-issuer=api \
  --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-api-audiences=api
```

After that creating ServiceAccount and applying pod.yaml works.

Comment: The above minikube command doesn't work with the last minikube version 1.8.2 , you need to use:
`minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.key --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-issuer=kubernetes/serviceaccount --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-api-audiences=api`

Answer (score 2):

you should use deployment since when you use deployment the token is automatically mounted into the pods.